# Проблема с ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-studio

Недавно начал изучать Android Studio, наткнулся на проблему. Когда я хочу добавить текст, кнопку и т.д на девайс, добавленные компоненты пропадают за экран телефона.

Затем выводится ошибка:

This view is not constrained. It only has designtime positions, so it will jump to (0,0) at runtime unless you add the constraints  The layout editor allows you to place widgets anywhere on the canvas, and it records the current position with designtime attributes (such as layout_editor_absoluteX). These attributes are not applied at runtime, so if you push your layout on a device, the widgets may appear in a different location than shown in the editor. To fix this, make sure a widget has both horizontal and vertical constraints by dragging from the edge connections.

Я перевел, но так и не смог решить проблему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Задайте ограничения (constraints) минимум для 2 сторон (по горизонтали и вертикали). Используя ConstraintLayout вы как бы говорите ей - этот элемент находится в верхнем левом углу (на скрине ниже). Под кнопкой у меня расположен RecyclerView. И я его ограничиваю следующим образом - левая, правая и нижняя стороны ограничиваются экраном устройства. Верхняя сторона "лежит под кнопкой".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 8):

`ConstraintLayout` требует подробной настройки расположения элементов основываясь на констреинтах (взаимном положении и т.д.) — он как продвинутый `RelativeLayout`.

Констреинты примерно означают "настройки положения вью" — куда должны "притягиваться" верх/низ и т.д., какой и где марджин, нужно ли как-то взаимодействовать с гайдлайнами.

В интернете информации более чем достаточно — читайте или [официальную доку](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/), или статейки вроде [этой](https://habr.com/company/touchinstinct/blog/326814/) (первая попавшаяся в гугле, вроде бы неплохо написана).

Ошибка говорит вам:

> This view is not constrained. It only has designtime positions, so it will jump to (0,0) at runtime unless you add the constraints

Вольный перевод:

> У вашего вью не настроены констреинты. Он имеет только настройку отображения в визуальном редакторе, а в рантайме (на устройстве) он прыгнет в точку (0, 0).

Также в редакторе есть магическая кнопочка (но помогает она не всегда, лучше вручную):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Она на основе того, как вы расположили в редакторе элементы, постарается настроить констреинты (правда, с кучей лишних марджинов и всего такого) вместо вас.